# Run multiple commands inside a new shell

Tags: cmd

I want to run a command in a new cmd window then close that window.

For example: `start "New Window" /D C:\Users tree`.
I then want that window to close.
`start "New Window" /D C:\Users tree&exit` doesn't work because the exit is applied to the original window. I then tried `start "New Window" /D C:\Users "tree&exit"` but that just errors.

Is there a way to group the end bit of the command so that it is executed in the new window?

Comment: `start "New Window" /D C:\Users tree ^& exit`? or `start "New Window" /D "C:\Users" cmd /C "tree & exit"`…

Comment: Thank you, both of these worked! @aschipfl